# In spite of his promiscuity why is Indra worshipped?

Tags: puranas, history, worship, indra

Indra was considered as king of Gods. But if we see his personal life, we learn that he has kidnapped many females few of whom were married and few were unmarried. Some of these were daughters/wives of Rishis/Kings.

So in spite of his promiscuity why is Indra worshipped by the people?

Comment: Indra is post like PM of India. Current Indra is Purandara Indra and see that question for how he became Indra. Yeah, Indra do face his Karma.

Comment: @The Destroyer Sir, what are good equalities of indradev?

Comment: Related: [Was the story of adultery of Indra in the story of Ahalya a PRAKSHIPTA?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9023/2995)

Comment: Related [Why Indra is not worshiped in general regular worship?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29118/why-indra-is-not-worshiped-in-general-regular-worship)