# Why Indra is not worshiped in general regular worship?

Tags: worship, indra, curse

We have story where Lord Brahma was cursed by Lord Shiva and Sage Bhrigu as discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19893/which-vedic-verses-declare-lord-brahma-as-supreme/22601#22601). And due to this reason(s), Lord Brahma is not worshiped in general regular worship.

Is there any similar curse given to Indra, the king of gods?

Comment: Indra is a deva, not Iswara. As Krishna says in the GIta...those who worship the gods go to the gods, those who worship Me attain Me. If you want to go a loka and be reborn again after you extinguish the deeds that got you to Indra, worship Indra. Up to you.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda that is WRONG. Indra is a vedic god and even rama and krishna worshipped him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7988/do-the-scriptures-say-anything-about-spiritual-possession/29117#29117), Indra tried to assault Ruchi, wife of the great ascetic Devasarman. And Devasarman's disciple Vipula (scion of Bhrigu's race) cursed Indra in the following words:

> Vipula said, 'O wicked-souled Purandara, O thou of sinful mind, **O wretch that hast no control over thy senses, neither the deities nor human beings will worship thee for any length of time!** Hast thou forgotten it. O Sakra,--does it not still dwell in thy remembrance,--that Gautama had cursed thee in consequence of which thy body became disfigured with a thousand sex-marks, which, owing to the Rishi's compassion, were afterwards changed into organs of vision? I know that thou art of an exceedingly foolish understanding, that thy soul is uncleansed, and that thou art of an exceedingly unstable mind! O fool, know that this lady is being protected by me. O sinful wretch, go back to that place whence thou tamest. O thou of foolish soul, I do not consume thee today into ashes with my energy. Verily, I am filled with compassion for thee. It is for this that I do not, O Vasava, wish to burn thee. My preceptor, endued with great intelligence, is possessed of terrible might. With eyes blazing with wrath, he would, if he saw thee, have burnt thy sinful self today. Thou shouldst not, O Sakra, do like this again. The Brahmanas should be regarded by thee. See that thou dost not, with thy sons and counsellors, meet with destruction, afflicted by the might of the Brahmanas. Thou thinkest that thou art an immortal and that, therefore, art at liberty to proceed in this way. Do not, however, disregard the Brahmanas. Know that there is nothing unattainable by penance.' ~ **[Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva: Section XLI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b006.htm)**

Comment: Why do you provide puranic or non Vedic reference for Vedic gods... Vedic matters should be referred to vedas. Downvoting it

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Is Brahma (Prajapati) not vedic god..?????...if why Brahma is not worshipped can be answered from Itihas-Puranas then why not Indra?...Also I don't consider Itihas-Puranas non vedic...I consider them [5th Veda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23409/12304)...and [vedas-are-incomplete-without-ithihas-and-puran](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/where-in-vedas-it-is-written-that-vedas-are-incomplete-without-ithihas-and-puran)..

Comment: its because of sectarian people  who degraded the Vedic gods to uphold their respective puranic gods. If you say they are fifth veda then which acharya has considered them equal ? Any thing against vedic gods is poison.

Comment: All Vedic gods are worshiped during vedic rites. They are not complete without it. In Puranic worship they might not be worshiped. Yes brahmaa and Indra all should be worshiped today as well

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I know that they are worshipped in Yajna but the Q is not during Yajna.... it's about general worship...we don't need Acharya's reference when Veda Vyasa himself claimed so at multiple places..

Comment: i.think you are not familiar with vedas and vedic worship. During sandhya vandan and many daily vedic rites these are worshiped. And during most of vedic samskaras including marriage. Further if you quote about pancham veda that would mean that mahabharata and puranas existed before Vedas so that they were mentioned? What vyasa said we dont know. In one of his padma purana he says six out of eighteen puranas leads one to hell.