# Which scripture mention Race among the Gods to marry Ahalya?

Tags: scripture, puranas, gods, indra

Nearly everyone knows the famous story of [Adulteration of Indra with Ahalya.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9023/was-the-story-of-adultery-of-indra-in-the-story-of-ahalya-a-prakshipta/9025#9025)
But there is a story of how Ahalya was married to Gautama Rishi.

I have heard there was competition among Gods to marry Ahalya.

[This website here](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/when-lord-indra-was-cursed-for-lust) also mentions the story I have heard. It tells:

> Brahma announced that **he would marry Ahalya to the person who would travel around the earth and come back first.** On hearing Brahma's words, all the Devtas and Rishis embarked upon their journey. At the same time, while going back to his ashram, Maharshi Gautama saw baby Kamdhenu (divine cow) taking birth. Looking at that site, the sage got overwhelmed by the prominence of the creator and out of respect, did a circumbulation of the cow and a Shivling....
>
> Brahma came to know everything through his meditation powers. He told Rishi Gautama that a cow which had given birth was equal to the earth with seven islands and to move around it (perform parikrama) and the Shivling was equal to travelling around Earth. Brahma was impressed by the patience, knowledge and penance of Rishi Gautam and told him that he deserved to get married to Ahalya.

**Which scripture mention this story of Race among Gods to marry Ahalya ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This story is mentioned in [Brahma Puran of Gautami Mahatmya, Chapter-16, Page No.- 819](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20270/3/Chapter%201-20_759-838p.pdf).

When lord Brahma has created Ahalya, everyone wanted to marry her.

> On seeing her, Indra, Agni, Varuna and other devas told me sevarally, "O Lord of
>       Devas, she should be given to me."

Gautama had also made some effort to get Ahalya.

> After Devas have gone, Gautama, the lord of sages, too made some effort like
>       this for the sake of Ahalya.
>
> In the meantime, O brahmin, the divine cow Kama-dhenu had partially delivered
>       her calf. Gautama saw her thus.
>
> Remembering "This is the Earth" be circumambulated her. Then he circumambulated
>       the Linga of the lord of Devas.
>
> After circumambulating both of them Gautama the excellent sage decided thus- "Devas
>       have not completed even one round of the Earth. I have completed two rounds." After
>       deciding thus, that sage came near me.

After that Gautama has said these word to Lord Brahma:

> O Brahma, the entire earth has been circumambulated by me. What is proper in this
>       connection? O lord of Devas, you know it better yourself.

Then Lord Brahma said following words to Gautama:

> By meditation I understood it and I said to Gautama: "The lady of beautiful
>       eyebrows will be given to you alone. The circumambulation has been completed.