# What are 8 sacrificial cups with a vedic deity

Tags: upanishads, vedic-gods

While reading [Brahma Upanishad](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmaup.htm) I encountered following line from verse 2

> And that state which he does not give up for a next one is called the waking state. (He carries all these states within himself) just as a (Vedic) deity bears the eight sacrificial cups simultaneously.

I have not seen any deity (especially vedic deity) carrying cups For e.g. following image of Rudra
[image: Rudra]

Comment: I think this is referring to cups of Soma.  Soma Yagnas would often involve offering multiple cups of Soma into the fire at one stretch to a single god.

Comment: What exactly is soma and what is soma Yagna does soma mean Nectar (amrita)

Comment: Soma is a drink that was derived from a plant whose identity is now unknown, but it's thought to be Ephedra by most modern scholars.  Soma was central to the performance of Vedic Yagnas, and Chandra the moon god is the god of the Soma drink as well; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5474/36 Soma and Amrita are not the same, but since the gods drink both of them and Chandra is the god of both drinks, Soma is often compared to Amrita in the Vedas.  Soma was drank by both Brahmins performing a Yagna and by the gods.  Amrita is a magical drink that's exclusive to the gods.