# Amalanadhipiran

Tags: vishnu, scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, alwar

Which Alwar is called as Amaladhipiran? How many hymns has he composed in nalayira divya prabandham? On which God he has sung the hymns? I came to know that God himself told the priest to carry this alwar on his shoulders as the former had thrown stone and blood started pouring from latter's head. Finally he merged with God's feet as a jyothi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Alwar you are referring to is Thiruppan Alwar, who was an incarnation of Vishnu's Srivatsa mark as I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7838/36).  He has composed exactly one poem in the Naalayira Divya Prabandham.  As you alluded to, he was carried into the Sri Rangam temple by Loka Saranga Muni, where upon seeing the Ranganatha statue (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6829/36)) he spontaneously composed a 10-verse poem called Amalanadipiran, which you can listen to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wyAc_8UTGo).  [Here](http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=153) is the meaning:

> The perfect-first-Lord is the radiant king of the celestials and resident of Venkatam surrounded by fragrant groves. His golden rule is just and blemish less. He made ​​me a slave of his devotees. He is the Lord of Arangam surrounded by lofty walls. O, his auspicious lotus feet have come to stay in my eyes!
>
> With glee in his heart, he measured the Earth; his crown touched the roof of the Universe. He is the Kakuthstha Lord Rama, who rained arrows and killed the Rakshasas clan: He is the Lord of Arangam surrounded by fragrant groves. My mind hovers over the red vestures on his dark frame!
>
> He stands in, the monkey forest of Venkatam hills over the North, worshipped by the celestials. He reclines on a serpent in Arangam. Over his sunset-red vesture, the beautiful lotus-seat of Brahma rises from his navel, obsessing my heart and spirit!
>
> He shot arrows and felled the ten heads of Ravana, the king of fortified Lanka. He is the ocean-hued reclining in Arangam where peacocks dance to the song of bumble-bees. Aho; the cummerbund over his belly remains in my heart and haunts me.
>
> Relieving me of my load of misdeeds, the Lord of Arangam made ​​me his devotee; and what is more, he entered into me. What great penance did I do, I do not know. O, His' auspicious garland-chest has possessed me!
>
> My Lord saved the crescent-crested Siva from sin. He swallowed, the world, the people, the space, the Earth, the seven mountains and all else. He resides in Arangam city surrounded by flower groves that hum with bees. O, see his neck elevates my spirits!
>
> He wields the discus and conch in his hands. His body is like a dark mountain. He is my master with a tall crown wafting the fragrance of Tulasi. He is the wonder-Lord of Arangam reclining on a serpent bed. Aho, his red lips have won my heart over!
>
> The first causes Lord, hard to reach even for the gods, the perfect Lord residing in Arangam, is the one who, tore into the tyrant Hiranya Kasipu's bowels. His face is set with dark wide red eyes. Aho, those eyes have made ​​me intemperate.
>
> He swallowed seven worlds and lay as a child on a fig leaf. He reclines on a serpent in Arangam. He wears a beautiful gem-set garland and a necklace of pearls on his dark frame. Aho, his matchless beauty has stolen my heart!
>
> The dark-hued Lord is, the Lord who came as a cowherd-lad and stole buffer, He is the Lord of gods, and the Lord of Arangam also. He has stolen my heart. After seeing my Lord of ambrosial delight, my eyes will see naught else.

Comment: It's funny that this question was asked today given that I was thinking about this around the time it was posted. BTW is Thiruvenkatam the only other Divya Desa mentioned by Thirupaan azhvar or is there some other hidden one(s)?

Comment: @Surya I think Sri Rangam and Tirupati are the only two, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Both--Srirangam is the correct place. Thirupan alwar belonged to a lower caste and sung Lord Ranganatha. Fortunately I belong to srirangam. Born and brought up but now in chennai

Comment: @Parthasarathy Yeah, Sri Rangam is definitely the correct place.  Surya and I were just discussing whether there are also references to other Divya Desams within the poem.  There are several references to Tirupati, for instance.

Comment: @KS - Thirupan alwar will sing from kollidam karai about Lord Ranganatha and the Lord likes his hymns. It is srirangam only.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Well, he does say things like "resident of Venkatam", so in that sense he is also referencing another Divya Desam in the poem.

Comment: @KS - To my knowledge he is so poor and resided in Uraiyur in Trichy. He was having an instrument made of bamboo which is known as Paan. He will sing song by operating this Paan. Hence he is known as paanalwar. Give me a day's time-- will refer the nalayira divya prabandam   special meaning  for all hymns to clear your doubt pertaining to thiruvengadam.

Comment: I think, tiruppan alwar is saying that the Lord of Venkatam is also the Same Lord of Arangam.

Comment: @Krishna Yes, of course Thiruppan Alwar is praising Vishnu in general.  Surya was just asking what Divya Desams other than Sri Rangam are alluded to in the poem.

Comment: @both tomorow will refer and reply to your question as thiruppan alwar has composed only 10 hymns in 4000 DP.

Answer (score 0):

**Amalanathipiran - Thaniyan**

> ThiruppaaN Azhwaar composed ten paasurams among the divya prabandham revered as "Amalanaadhipiraan" Prabhandham. All 10 pasurams praise our Arangan. As ThiruppaaN Azhwaar has not sung on any other divya desa perumal, Arangan gets the distinction of being sung by 11 Aazhwars.
>
> This Azhwaar's prabhandham is different from all the other aazhwaar's
>   prabhandhams in that it does not contain any upadesams, critique of Veda-
>   Baahya Mathams, messages sent to the Lord as His Naayaki et al.
>   Thiruppaanar's prabhandham is an aanandha-lahari (limitless outpourings of the
>   bliss of aanandham) at the anubhavam of the Lord's Sarvaanga Soundharyam
>   and its redeeming effect. Azhwaar is totally lost in that blissful anubhavam
>   and the ten paasurams arose from him as "the revelational hymns".
>
> Let me contemplate on TiruppaanaAzhwar (Munivahana, the saint who was
>   carried to the precincts of the shrine of Lord Ranganatha, by
>   Lokasarangamamuni on his shoulders), whose inner soul (antaratma) became
>   enraptured at the sight of the reclining Lord Hari (Ranganatha) betwixt (the
>   two streams of) the river Kaveri, and who, having experienced (the vision of
>   the Lord) from the feet to His head declared that his eyes would not see any
>   other objects (except the Lord).
>
> Let us sing in praise of the holy feet of Sri ThiruppaanaAzhwar, who entered
>   (the holy shrine of Lord Ranganatha) riding on the shoulders of the sage
>   (Lokasaranga-Mahamuni) saw(the Lord in full) and sung (in praise) HIM limb by
>   limb, as the Lord showed to him, i. e., the lotus feet, the silk garment, the
>   navel, the waist band of rare excellence, the holy chest, the neck, the red
>   mouth (with rosy lips), the eyes of unfading (red lotus charm) and the (whole
>   divine) Archa form.

ThiruppaaN Azhwaar ThiruvadigaLE SaraNam.

> Thirupanlawar has composed 10 verses on the lord of srirangam and thiruvengadam. if we take the first letter of the first verse "Amalanadhi piran adiyar ..", first letter of the second verse " uvanda ulaathinay ......" and first letter of third verse " Mandi Pai Vada ... " , it means aum or pranvam. similarly if we were to take the first letter of fifth pasuram "Paramaya Pazhavinay ..." , first letter of sixth pasuram "Thunda Ven Pirayaan .. " and also the first letter of seventh pasuram " Kaiyinar Suri Sanga ..... " it means Padhuka .
>   **Source --- Nalayira divya Prabandham**