# Why is Samaveda considered inauspicious

Tags: vedas, sama-veda

I have read in manu-smriti that the yajurveda is ment for humans rigveda is for devtas (gods and demigods) and samveda is for pitrigana's(ancestral spirits).
So if samgayan (chanting of samveda) is happening you cannot read or chant any of the hynms of Yajurveda or Rigveda (i.e Andhaya).

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in my questions [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5245/36), [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5443/36) and [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6582/36), where I try to find the origins and role of an important Sama Veda song quoted in the Taittiriya Upanishad.  The second question contains a link to an mp3 file of the hymn (but you should be careful about listening to it, given that there are rules about the circumstances under which the Vedas can be heard).

Comment: yeah I have dont do mp3 listening because of same reasons by the way can I ask a specific question about andhayaya with some detailed explanations

Comment: Do you mean Anadhyaya?  Anadhyaya refers to the holidays where Vedas shouldn't be studied.

Comment: Yeah andhyaya means an+adyaya = no study (of vedas). I have a doubt regarding some points of andhayaya when there is too much wind or when wind blows sand and when there is no sunlight in morning prayers(sandhya time) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [chapter 4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu04.htm) of the Manu Smriti doesn't say that only the Yajur Veda is meant for humans. All the Vedas are meant to be chanted among men, it's just a question of whom each Veda is sacred to:

> 123. Let him never recite the Rig-veda or the Yagur-veda while the Saman (melodies) are heard; (let him stop all Veda-study for a day and a night) after finishing a Veda or after reciting an Aranyaka.
> 124. The Rig-veda is declared to be sacred to the gods, the Yagur-veda sacred to men, and the Sama-veda sacred to the manes; hence the sound of the latter is impure (as it were).

That is to say, the Rig Veda is concerned with praise of the gods, the Yajur Veda is concerned with the details of Yagnas that benefit Man, and the Samaveda consists of songs some of which are used to venerate the spirits of ancestors.

Now far as whether the Sama Veda is impure, the word impure is just being used metaphorically, in the sense that customs regarding the Sama Veda are similar to customs regarding impure things.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xTQpAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA148&ots=NosVF4JT1v&dq=%22while%20the%20Saman%20(melodies)%20are%20heard%22&pg=PA148#v=onepage&q&f=false) is what Medhatithi says in his commentary on the Manu Smriti:

> It is not really impure, but when it is heard, one must not study, just as in the presence of some impure thing or person.