# Is there a list of corresponding hymns between the Rig and Sama Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, sama-veda

I've been deeply researching Hinduism as of late, and recently have been learning about the Samaveda, it's distinctions from the Rigveda and it's overall purpose. A thought recently came to me:
The Samaveda is (as one post put it) a 'remix' of the Rigveda, the hymns are modified from the Rigveda for singing. Is there any place by chance that has a list equating verses of the Sama and Rig Vedas?

For example, I noticed that in the first decade of the Samaveda, the 8th verse reads

> May Vatsa draw thy mind away even from thy loftiest dwelling place! Agni, I yearn for thee with song.

which is lifted from Manadala 8, Hymn 11 of the Rigveda. I would love to have a list of such parallels as there are definitely certain verses of the Rigveda I would like to try to find in the Samaveda.

Comment: Related question as you are interested in Sama Veda and Rig Veda [Which verses of the Sama Veda are not taken from the Rig Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16123/5212).

Answer (score 1):

OM namaH sAmavedAya

Yes. Here is a complete [list of references to the Rigveda](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.180573/page/n367/mode/2up).

Comment: This appears to be a link-only answer. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."